# Scheme variadic function to add numbers

Tags: scheme

I've got this code

```
(define mysum
    (lambda (l)
        (if (null? l)
            0
            (+ (car l) (mysum (cdr l))))))
```

which works:

```
(mysum '(1 2 3))
```

gives 6, but this

```
(define (my+func . numbers)
  (lambda (num)
    (if (null? num)
        0
        (+ (car num) (my+func (cdr num))))) numbers)
```

isn't working. I'm getting lost trying to do recursion inside the lambda, no doubt. Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two ways to make a procedure. You have this:

```scm
(define name (lambda (arg ...) body ...))
```

And there is the equal syntactic sugar:

```scm
(define (name arg ...) body ...))
```

If you want to you can do the reverse process with your last procedure:

```scm
(define my+func 
  (lambda numbers
    (lambda (num) 
      (if (null? num)
          0
          (+ (car num) (my+func (cdr num)))))
    numbers))
```

When you do `(my+func 1 2 3)` it creates a procedure that takes one argument. Since the procedure is not the last expression it's discarded and thrown away and the last expression is `numbers`. Thus you'll get `(1 2 3)` as the result.

This would work:

```scm
(define my+func 
  (lambda numbers
    (if (null? numbers)
        0
        (+ (car numbers) (apply my+func (cdr numbers))))))
```

Which can be translated back to the sugared `define`:

```scm
(define (my+func . numbers) 
  (if (null? numbers)
      0
      (+ (car numbers) (apply my+func (cdr numbers)))))
```

Notice the `apply`. It's because you cannot send `(my+func '(2 3))` as the recursion but it needs to be `(my+func 2 3)` and that is what `apply` does. Alternatively you can make a helper that uses lists instead:

```scm
(define (my+func . numbers) 
  (define (helper ns)
    (if (null? ns)
        0
        (+ (car ns) (helper (cdr ns)))))
  (helper numbers))
```

Usually one would choose the  same name for the numbers in the helper, but I remember that I was confused the the shadowing variables that were not the same.